# How to select a n-1 object atributte if it exists or another n-1 object if it doesn't usin HQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, coalesce

I think the title does explain itself, I must select an attribute, as e.g a name,  from an object or another, following a specific order.

Like, "select my mom's name, if she exists, if not then get daddy's one, if even he doesn't exist so get any relative's name (it's n-1 yet)".

I think it would look like 'select coalesce(mom.name,dad.name,relative.name,"none of them exist") from MyEntity', if my entity looked like

```
public class MyEntity {

@ManyToOne
private Mom mom;

@ManyToOne
private Dad dad;

@ManyToOne
private Relative relative;

}
```

Here is the query:

```
session.createQuery("select m.dataEnvio as dataEnvio, " + 
    " m.txtAnotacoes as txtAnotacoes, " + 
    " coalesce(m.unidadeOrigem,m.unidadeDestino,m.pessoaOrigem) " + 
    " as nomeOrigem from Movimentacao m")
        .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Movimentacao.class))
        .list();
```

Comment: Show your complete query.

Comment: As this entity was made just to exemplify my issue, that one above would be the 'complete' query. 

The original one looks like

session.createQuery("select m.dataEnvio as dataEnvio,m.txtAnotacoes as txtAnotacoes,                   coalesce(m.unidadeOrigem,m.unidadeDestino,m.pessoaOrigem) as nomeOrigem from Movimentacao m").setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Movimentacao.class)).list();

Comment: So, you're not really accessing fields from the associated entities as you're doing in your post. The query is quite different. Anyway, you need left joins. `m.unidadeOrigem` generates an inner join. `select coalesce(mom.name, dad.name, "none") from MyEntity m left join m.mom mom left join m.dad dad`

Comment: I need to make it explicity? I thought it would be generated as those relationships are eager by default. Thanks

Comment: The fact that the relationships are eager doesn't change anything to the type of join a query generates. Navigating through associations using foo.bar.baz.blam genaretes inner joins.